# Url.RouteUrl is blank in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are in the process of upgrading an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project to ASP.NET 3.0 that uses EndPoint routing.

We have a large list of urls constructed with `Url.RouteUrl` using named routes, e.g. :

```
string url = Url.RouteUrl("blog-details", new { title = item.Title, id = item.Id });
// returns correct link of https://example.org/us/blog/some-title-6 in 2.2 but is blank in 3.0

[Route("~/{lang}/blog/{title}-{id}", Name= "blog-details")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string title, int id)
{
}
```

After upgrading to 3.0 those urls just produces a blank href. Our `startup.cs` is looking like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new MiddlewareFilterAttribute(typeof(LocalizationPipeline))); 
})
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder)
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);

services.AddRazorPages();
... 
}
```

We have tried replacing with below but that creates the wrong link and does not allow us to reuse as a variable, e.g.:

```
<a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Blog" asp-route-title="item.Title" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Link here</a>
url = Url.Action("Details", "Blog", new { id = item.Id, title = item.Title });
url = Url.RouteUrl(new { action = "Details", controller = "Blog", id = item.Id, title = item.Title });

// all returns https://example.org/us/blog/details/6?title=some-title 

<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Pricing">Pricing</a>
// returns https://example.org/us/home/pricing instead of correct https://example.org/us/pricing

[Route("~/{lang}/pricing")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Pricing()
{
    ...
}
```

This works, however:

```
<a asp-controller="Signup" asp-action="Customer">Sign up</a>
// returns correct https://example.org/us/signup/customer

[Route("~/{lang}/signup/customer")]
public IActionResult Customer()
{
   ...
}
```

What are we doing wrong if we want to use EndPoint routing (not the old 2.2.-way)?

Comment: That seems the `lang` is null after migration to 3.0 app , check Globalization and localization in your 3.0 app.

Comment: @NanYu Hmm... could be but we added 

`options.Filters.Add(new MiddlewareFilterAttribute(typeof(LocalizationPipeline)));` 
to avoid decorating all controllers. 
Also added 

`services.AddRouting(options =>
            { options.ConstraintMap.Add("lang", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint)); });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two items that are responsible for this behavior.

First, let's look at how the routes are generated:

```
[Route("~/{lang}/pricing")]
```

the `{lang}` token is the problematic one. One would expect that when browsing from page to page - as it was the case under ASP.Net Core 2.2 - this value would be retained and re-used. It is not the case anymore. The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#endpoint-routing-differences-from-earlier-versions-of-routing) justifies it using the `id` example: `book id 123` should not lead to `login user id 123`. Unfortunately, the same applies to the much more stable language code `lang`.

The URL generation must therefore include the `lang` code. Using the 1st URL in the question, it would become:

```
string url = Url.RouteUrl("blog-details", new {lang="en", title = item.Title, id = item.Id });

[Route("~/{lang}/blog/{title}-{id}", Name= "blog-details")]
```

The second item is the default route. Since the route you though was not matched because of the missing `lang` parameter, the default route is used.  Since you have used parameters that are not part of the default route template, they are added to the end of the URL (`?title=some-title`). If there is no default route, no URL at all is generated.

There is an interesting [post](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12794) on the issue that is worth reading.

On a side note for all readers, one can extract the ambient value that should be recycled and plug it in links generations:

```
@{string lang = (string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["lang"]; }
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="myController" asp-action="myAction" asp-route-lang=@lang >click here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! This answer deserves more visibility, it took me a while to find it

Comment: In my case missing token was at the controller level `[Route("Api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")] internal class XController`.